# Migrating attachments 2003->2010

Tags: 2010, upgrade, attachments, 2003

Whats the easiest way to merge attached files from Sharepoint 2003 to Sharepoint 2010? We are upgrading. I can copy the list but not the files attached because they are still connected to the old site.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question:
Your issue is, you are migrating from sharepoint 2003 to SharePoint 2010. I am thinking two possible solution.

1. Migrate the content database from SharePoint 2003 to 2007 to 2010
2. your worry free solution is, use 3rd party tool i.e MetaLogix or ShareGate or AvePoint or Dell. All have the trial version, if you dont have larger size of data then trial will solve your problem.

Comment: I vote for option #1. I've had a lot of issues with migration tools - definitely not "worry free" in those cases.

Comment: Without knowing how much content you're talking about I would recommend #2...and vouch for the Metalogix and ShareGate tools.